# Rotate a Sprite around another Sprite -libGDX-

Tags: rotation, libgdx, sprite

[video game link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z_s6EPxJsts&feature=em-upload_owner)

I'm trying to make a game (see link above) , and I need to have the stick rotate around himself to maintain the orientation face to center of the circle.

this is how I declare the Sprite, and how I move it around the circle:

declaration:

```
    line = new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("drawable/blockLine.png")));
    line.setSize(140, 20);
    lineX = Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2 - line.getWidth()/2;
    lineY = (Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2 - line.getHeight()/2) + circle.getHeight()/2;
```

movement:

```
     Point point = rotatePoint(new Point(lineX, lineY), new Point(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2), angle+= Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() * lineSpeed);
     line.setPosition(point.x, point.y);
```

rotatePoint function:

```
    Point rotatePoint(Point point, Point center, double angle){

    angle = (angle ) * (Math.PI/180); // Convert to radians

    float rotatedX = (int) (Math.cos(angle) * (point.x - center.x) - Math.sin(angle) * (point.y-center.y) + center.x);

    float rotatedY = (int) (Math.sin(angle) * (point.x - center.x) + Math.cos(angle) * (point.y - center.y) + center.y);

    return new Point(rotatedX,rotatedY);

}
```

Any sugestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test right now but I think the rotation of the line should simply be:

`Math.atan2(rotatedPoint.getOriginX() - middlePoint.getOriginX(), rotatedPoint.getOriginY() - middlePoint.getOriginY()));`

Then you'll have to adjust rad to degrees or whatever you'll use. Tell me if it doesn't work!

Comment: I used it like that,                                                                                           
`line.setRotation((float) Math.atan2(point.x - Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2, point.y - Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2))`                                                          but it doesn't work

Comment: Hmm as I said I can't test now unfortunately, I make a game where I have this shield effect that rotates around the object being hit, very similar to what you are trying to achieve and I use this code: `shieldEffect.setRadiansToImpact((float) Math.atan2(shieldEffect.getX() - this.getOriginX(), shieldEffect.getY() - this.getOriginY()));

shieldEffect.setRotation((float) (shieldEffect.getRadiansToImpact() * -180 / Math.PI)-45);` The hardcoded -45 is just due to how I've painted the texture.

Comment: `shieldEffect.setRotation((float) (shieldEffect.getRadiansToImpact() * -180 / Math.PI)-45)`

this rotate the object1 around object2 or rotate the object1 around itself ?

Comment: Im my case this rotates the shield effect to face the object being hit (the middle), in your case it would be the rotating the line to face the midpoint

Comment: I don't  think it's the same as I am looking for.

I need something like a matemathics formula to have the stick remain on the margin of the circle, somehow..

Comment: `float var = ((float) Math.atan2(line.getX() - Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2, line.getY() - Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2)); 

line.setRotation((float) (var * -180 / Math.PI));`

this is how I implemented, and this is how it looks:
[link4video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kcSZMvglLGQ&feature=youtu.be)
it seems to have a little problem, the circle is a .png with same width and height.

Comment: oh! it works !
It was my fault, _line.getX()_, it doesn't give me the center of the line, it gives the left-upperSide of the line.. so now it works. I will accept your answer, 10x

Answer (score 0):

I would take a different approach, I just created a method that places n Buttons around a click on the screen. I am using something that looks like this:

```
float rotation; // in degree's
float distance; //Distance from origin (radius of circle).
vector2 originOfRotation; //Center of circle
vector2 originOfSprite; //Origin of rotation sprite we are calculating
Vector2 direction = new vector2(0, 1); //pointing up

//rotate the direction
direction.rotate(rotation);
// add distance based of the direction. Warning: originOfRotation will change because of chaining method.
// use originOfRotation.cpy() if you do not want to init each frame
originOfSprite = originOfRotation.add(direction.scl(distance));
```

Now you have the position of your sprite. You need to increment `rotation` by x each frame to have it rotate. If you want the orientation of the sprite to change you can use the direction vector, probably rotated by 180 again. Efficiency wise I'm not sure what the difference would be.